# PREG_MATCH check all words and condition

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I've written a regular expression which seraches the search terms in OR condition, such that provided three words have in string irrespective of their order. Now i want to just put an AND condition as I want to get ALL THREE words simulatniously in a string with different order.

Here's my `preg_match()` regular expresison.

```
$myPregMatch = (preg_match("/\b^(Word1|Word2|Word3)\b/", "Word4 Word2 Word1 Word3 Word5 Word7"));
 if ($myPregMatch){
    echo  "FOUND !!!";
 }
```

I want to find in string `"Word4 Word2 Word1 Word3 Word5 Word7"` that all words are in it with different order. and if sample string is `"Word5 Word7 Word3 Word2"` then it shouldn't returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need anchored look-aheads:

```
^(?=.*\bWord1\b)(?=.*\bWord2\b)(?=.*\bWord3\b)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tZ5zS6/2)

If there are newline symbols in the input string, you need to use an `/s` modifier.

Here is an [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/EXx4kf):

```
$re = '/^(?=.*\bWord1\b)(?=.*\bWord2\b)(?=.*\bWord3\b)/'; 
$str = "Word4 Word2 Word1 Word3 Word5 Word7"; 

$myPregMatch = (preg_match($re, $str));
 if ($myPregMatch){
    echo  "FOUND !!!";
 }
```

Result: `FOUND !!!`

Answer (score 2):

it maybe faster to check every word

```
$string = "Word4 Word2 Word1 Word3 Word5 Word7";  // input string

$what = "Word2 Word1 Word3";                      // words to test
$words = explode(' ', $what);                     // Make array

$i = count($words);
while($i--) 
   if (false == strpos($string, $words[$i])) 
     break;

$result = ($i==-1);   // if $i == -1 all words are present in input string
```

Comment: This is good or the sample demo string, but in reality, there will be full stops, commas, semi-colons, etc, and whole word search will become impossible without regex.